# How to create multiple copies of rows by multiplication in pandas?

Tags: python, pandas

I have a file with several columns, one of which is  an attribute called count. This indicates that there are multiple counts of the same score.

I want to multiply the number of rows so that it is representative of the number found in column count.

I tried using `dataframe.mul` but that multiplied the count values and returned `NaN` for the string values.

What function should I call to accomplish my goal?
e.g.

```
"Survey"   List    Question    Description Option  Count
C3 2O15 Survey      Rate the Hotel & Accomodations      Fair    2
```

Should be transformed to:

```
"Survey"   List    Question    Description Option  Count
C3 2O15 Survey      Rate the Hotel & Accomodations      Fair    2
C3 2O15 Survey      Rate the Hotel & Accomodations      Fair    2
```

This was my flawed previous attempt

```
import pandas as pd 

data = pd.read_excel('/Users/dheepan.ramanan/Documents/C3Data/structureddata.xlsx')
main = pd.DataFrame(data)
multiplier = pd.DataFrame(data['Count'])
main.mul(multiplier)

 Count Description List Option Question ï»¿"Survey"
0      121         NaN  NaN    NaN      NaN         NaN
1      100         NaN  NaN    NaN      NaN         NaN
```

Sorry if this is a simple question, I'm new to pandas.

Thanks!

Comment: This doesn't seem very efficient.  What are you really trying to accomplish?

Comment: If you know of a better way let me know.

Essentially for every record the count varies between 2-22 and there are about 160 records. So I want to replicate the row so that the respond counts are representative.

So 16 people wrote fair for question X. Where as right now it merely says count 16 but only one fair response.

I am trying to avoid copying and pasting the lines in excel.

Comment: This you should do a groupby on option and apply a sum and retrieve the count...

Comment: After you duplicate your rows (e.g. 16 rows), what do you plan to do with your expanded DataFrame?

Comment: Sorry if I was being confusing, it seems that groupby is not what I am looking for in this case.

The expanded dataframe is basically going to be used in a pivot table like fashion to see how respondents graded various questions.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't think Pandas is tailored for such applications (more like dropping duplicate rather than creating them).

---

**Edit:** I saw what you were actually trying to achieve (counting the number of 'Options') after I answered, but for this you should try `df.groupby(by='Option').sum()['Count']`

---

Anyways, here is something that works:

```
In [1]: # Create some sample data to play with
df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randn(3,2), columns=['A', 'B'])
df['Count'] = np.random.random_integers(1,3,3)
df.index = ['C'+str(x) for x in df.index]
df = np.round(df,1)
df

Out[1]:
     A       B      Count
C0  1.6     2.0     3
C1  0.7     1.6     2
C2  0.9     -0.4    1

In [2]: # Function to duplicate rows
def duplicate_rows(df, countcol):
    for _, row in df.iterrows():
        for i in range(int(row[countcol])-1):
            # Append this row at the end of the DataFrame
            df = df.append(row)

    # Remove countcol (could do a drop too to do that...)
    notcountcols = [x for x in df.columns if x != countcol]
    df = df[notcountcols]
    # optional: sort it by index
    df.sort_index(inplace=True)
    return df

 In [3]: 
 df_dup = duplicate_rows(df, 'Count')
 df_dup

 Out[3]:
     A       B
C0  1.6     2.0
C0  1.6     2.0
C0  1.6     2.0
C1  0.7     1.6
C1  0.7     1.6
C2  0.9     -0.4
```

Comment: AH! Thank you! You were right the first time. Sorry if I was confusing, although that groupby function looks very useful. I'll have to try that later.

So far I've only used pandas for merges and sorting, but I want to learn more. 

One question I had is 
`df = np.round(df,1)` 
This line is just rounding the columns A and B correct? Just making sure. 
Thanks for your help again

Comment: Yes, this line is just because having 5 digits was making my formatting of table on stack overflow more difficult :).

For you you just need the function and to apply it to your dataframe

Comment: (Can you upvote the answer as well as accepting it please?)